# Example in Python of using Javascript with WebDriver to fire blur action

Tags: python, selenium, blur

I'm trying to use Selenium/Webdriver to test a web application with Python.  Being new to Selenium, I've started with the Selenium IDE to provide a base for generating the required Python code.

The application I'm trying to automate has a series of fields (user, password, password confirmation) that performs a variety of validation steps (password length, strength, ect) after the user enters information.  I've gotten this to work in the IDE by using the FireEvent focus and blur commands on the elements.

However, Webdriver does not support the use of FireEvent, as users don't fire events.

I've tried a variety of methods to try and get this to work, including using click on another element and sending a TAB key after the input value.  Nothing seems to work.

In researching for a solution, I've come across some messages that suggest using javascript or jquery to perform a blur action.  I haven't found a example yet that shows how to do this in Python or through the IDE.

I'd be very interested if someone could provide a example, or had any other suggestions to try.